# Golang: the hang of fmt.Printf stdout happened next to fmt.Scan stdin in the for loop

Tags: go

As title, it's hard for me to describe the problem. So I showed the sample code, input and output below.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    for i := 1; i <= 3; i++ {
        var a, b, c string
        fmt.Scan(&a)
        fmt.Scan(&b)
        fmt.Scan(&c)
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", a)
    }
}
```

Input

```
a b c
d e f
g h i
```

Expected Output

```
a
d
g
```

However, the actual output printed "a", "d" first. Then, after pressing **return (enter)** key, "g" was printed. This was actual output.

---

*Update*

If I pasted whole nine characters, the third iteration was hung.
However, if I merely enter character one after another, it met the expected output.

Comment: you are seeing expected behaviour ... what do you want which you are not seeing ?   ...  in addition to being interactive , you can save your input into a file then  issue  ` cat  /my/file |  myprogram  `   then you will see a, d and g each on its own line

Comment: In third interation it hangs on scanning to &c, looking for whitespace. Return (enter) is counted also as whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you enter that input without a **return (enter)** ?

If you run this interactively and actually typing in all the input I think you'll understand the reason for the output.

You will have to:

- Type `a b c` - nothing will output yet as the third `Scan` does not know if `c` is all you'll type
- Press `return (enter)` - only at this point you'll see the `a` output
- Do the same for the other lines

Take a look at the doc for `Scan` which explains this as well:

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Scan